# How to deal with Covariancy in Scala types from Java

Tags: java, scala, covariance

In our Scala project we use types that contain covariant type parameters to communicate decisions.

```scala
sealed trait ArbiterResponse[+Tasks]

object Reject extends ArbiterResponse[Nothing]

trait Proceed[Tasks] extends ArbiterResponse[Tasks]
object Proceed extends Proceed[Nothing]
case class ProceedConditionally[Tasks](tasks : Tasks) extends Proceed[Tasks]
```

When using this from Java I get an error that a `ArbiterResponse<SomeTask>` can't be converted to a `Reject$` in:

```java
final ArbiterResponse<SomeTask> response = ???
if (task instanceof Reject$) { ... }
```

> error: incompatible types: ArbiterResponse cannot be converted to Reject$

How can I work around this issue? I suppose this is because the Java compiler has no knowledge of co-/contravariance. I work around this by adding flags that describe what kind of `ArbiterResponse` a response is. But I don't really like this solution as it is quite some manual, error-prone, work. Who has a better idea?

```scala
sealed trait ArbiterResponse[+Tasks] {
  def isRejected: Boolean
  def isProceed: Boolean
  def isProceedConditionally: Boolean
}

object Reject extends ArbiterResponse[Nothing] {
  def isRejected = true
  def isProceed = false
  def isProceedConditionally = false
}

trait Proceed[Tasks] extends ArbiterResponse[Tasks] {
  def isRejected = false
  def isProceed = true
  def isProceedConditionally = false
}
object Proceed extends Proceed[Nothing]

case class ProceedConditionally[Tasks](tasks : Tasks) extends Proceed[Tasks] {
  override def isProceedConditionally = true
}
```

Comment: haha. I am sorry. Haha. To even have the audacity to call scala code from java is very courageous. I am sorry, this comment doesn't help I know, but the direction you are in, you are bound to get stuck! Its futile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite tricky in most of the circumstances to call scala code from java. But in any case, if you wish to go via type-casting way, then this is how you can:

```
    for (Object response : Arrays.asList(new ProceedConditionally("asdf"), Reject$.MODULE$)) {
        if(Reject$.class.isInstance(response)){
            Reject$ cast = Reject$.class.cast(response);
            System.out.println(cast);
        }else if(Proceed.class.isInstance(response)){
            System.out.println("Proceed");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Nothing: "+response.getClass());
        }
    }
```

prints

> Proceed
>
> prac.Reject$@266474c2

But it might soon break with different scala versions or would be tricky to get it right. One way would probably be to via visitor pattern way. It is not completely satisfactory but might be helpful

```
sealed trait ArbiterResponse[+Tasks]{
  def doSomething
}

object Reject extends ArbiterResponse[Nothing]{
  def doSomething = ???
}

trait Proceed[Tasks] extends ArbiterResponse[Tasks]
object Proceed extends Proceed[Nothing]{
  def doSomething = ???
}
case class ProceedConditionally[Tasks](tasks : Tasks) extends Proceed[Tasks]{
  def doSomething = println(tasks)
}
```